# Named query and pagination

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am trying to use named query with pagination of elements, but I am not a database expert and the answers I found didn't help much, will be thankful for some help, code :

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Object.byName", query = "select a from OBJECT a where a.name=?"),

})
```

using : `findByNamedQuery("Object.byName", a);`

I know I need to use `setFirstResult(x);` and `setMaxResults(y);` but how to use them with `findByNamedQuery`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to work with the session/entity manager directly:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Object.byName");
q.setFirstResult(x);
q.setMaxResults(pageSize);
//set the parameters here
return q.list();
```

This is the JPA syntax, hibernate's is almost the same.

Comment: @seismael - are you using spring's HibernateTemplate?